# Unable to install google chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, google-chrome

I've been trying to install .deb chrome file (google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb) but unable to do. I only get the message saying that "It is not installable" and "Some packages could not be installed".

logs:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Unsupported file ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb given on commandline
```

Note, selecting 'google-chrome-stable:amd64' instead of './google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

```
google-chrome-stable:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable                                                                         
                      Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable 
Recommends:: command not found
ubuntu@ip-:~$ E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E:: command not found
```

Comment: Which version of Xubuntu are you using?

Comment: Please provide data with regard to the version of your OS and the architecture of your CPU.

Comment: have you tried installing the dependencies from launchpad.net by yourself?

Comment: @bitdruid These dependencies should be available in supported versions of Ubuntu. For an example, see http://packages.ubuntu.com/libasound2 . One should not need to go to Launchpad to install Chrome. OP might be using an older version of Ubuntu, and we need clarifications about that.